# Implementing A timer into fall damage phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I'm trying To implement Fall damage into my game, and This is my code so far,

```js
this.fallDmgAmt = 1;
    if (
      this.player.body.onFloor() == false &&
      this.player.body.velocity.y >= 300
    ) {
      //console.log("falling");
      this.falling = true;
      this.clock.start();
    }

    if (this.player.body.onFloor() == true && this.falling == true) {
      this.health = this.health - this.fallDmgAmt;
      this.changeHealth(this.health);
      this.falling = false;
      return;
    }
```

I want to add A timer to this, so i can track the amount of time fell and then apply damage. How can i do this? I tried `the rexrainbow clock plugin` but that also doesn't work.

code update

```js
//fall damage
    this.fallDmgAmt = 1;
    if (
      this.player.body.onFloor() == false &&
      this.player.body.velocity.y >= 300
    ) {
      //console.log("falling");
      this.falling = true;
      this.startTick = this.tick;
      console.log(this.tick)
      return;
    }

    if (this.player.body.onFloor() == true && this.falling == true) {
      this.fallDmgAmt = (this.tick-this.startTick)/100
      this.health = this.health - this.fallDmgAmt;
      if (this.health <= 0) {
        this.health = 0;
        this.scene.launch("death");
        this.health = 10;
        this.changeHealth(this.health);
        this.scene.pause();
      }
      this.changeHealth(this.health);
      this.falling = false;
      return;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calculating fall damage? Or how should the time effect the damage? can you share some more details?

Comment: I wanted to add to fall damage for every amount of time, like. say every second, and when he hit the ground, i would apply all that damage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a easy an better solution would be just to get the current time, on fall start and calculate the difference on fall. *No plugin needed.*

**Here your code adapted for that idea:**

```
this.fallDmgAmt = 1;
if (
  this.player.body.onFloor() == false &&
  this.player.body.velocity.y >= 300  && 
  this.falling == false
) {
  this.falling = true;
  this.fallStartTime = (new Date()).getTime(); // milliseconds
}

if (this.player.body.onFloor() == true && this.falling == true) {
  let fallDurationInSeconds = ((new Date()).getTime() - this.fallStartTime) / 1000;
  this.health = this.health - (this.fallDmgAmt * fallDurationInSeconds );
  this.changeHealth(this.health);
  this.falling = false;
  return;
}
```

Comment: I did actually figure out how to use a timer in phaser and it works a lot like this

Comment: but i have. an issue in the fact that this is in update, and so the fall start time changes every update to match the current time

Comment: @VatsaPandey I update my answer, I though your code work already. Adding this extra check should prevent the updating of the time.